# Moving a row to the top of an unbound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a form created which an unbound datagridview that has three columns. "Position", "ID", "Name". The data is being added at runtime into a database upon the forms completion. (I don't want to add unnecessary rows to the database in the event a person clicks Cancel.)

What I need to do is on the deletion of a row in the datagridview, search through the rows "Position" for a "HJ" value. If it's not found, change the "Position" value of the first row to be "HJ".

Here's a photo of what I mean:

[image: Screenshot]

I've already taken care of the "Add Judge" button. The "Make Head Judge" button I guess will be on another question.

EDIT: Code removed, not needed since I found a function to search through a datagridview for me.

I found information about `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` but I can't seem to get it to work for some reason. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a hidden column "rank" which could be used to sort the grid. Enumerate each of your ranks: HeadJudge = 0, AsstHeadJudge = 1, Judge = 2. If you will only have one head judge, then sorting by rank will always place the HeadJudge in the first row.

Comment: Okay something just came into mind. How would I cause the datagrid to sort automatically on a row add?

Comment: Use the RowsAdded event for the DataGrid to call Sort method like this: 
`DataGridView1.Sort(Rank, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)`